# How to fix my images so they show in internet explorer 11

Tags: wordpress, image, jpeg

Images wont show in Internet Explorer 10 or 11, they do on the newer browsers tho

https://gegen-das-vergessen-meissen.de/ supposed to be big image, instead of black background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, The image is displaying on IE Edge and emulated IE 10 & 11 But with a warning about Mixed content.

Perhaps is it hidden on your computer because of security rules.

You should replace your call to background image:

```
.elementor-155 .elementor-element.elementor-element-0a3c09b:not(.elementor-motion-effects-element-type-background), .elementor-155 .elementor-element.elementor-element-0a3c09b > .elementor-motion-effects-container > .elementor-motion-effects-layer {

    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    background-image: url("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/forget-me-not-316354_neu.jpg");
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;

}
```

Replace the http with https:

```
background-image: url("https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/forget-me-not-316354_neu.jpg");
```